# Layout not in proper structure/container is overflow - What is wrong in the CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my desired layout:
[image]

And this is my rendered layout
[image]

These are my CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

#code-html,
#code-css,
#code-js {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#code-html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

#code-css {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#code-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#main-run {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#main-display {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <section id="code-html">section 1</section>
      <section id="code-css">section 2</section>
      <section id="code-js">section 3</section>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <section id="main-run">sub-head</section>
      <section id="main-display">main display</section>
    </main>
  </article>
</body>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Why is there an overlap at the bottom of the screen. I want the main element to take all the available width. Also, the height of aside element is more than 100vh. All the contents should fit into the screen without a scroll bar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
 
}

#code-html,
#code-css,
#code-js {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#code-html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#code-css {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#code-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#main-run {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#main-display {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <section id="code-html">section 1</section>
      <section id="code-css">section 2</section>
      <section id="code-js">section 3</section>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <section id="main-run">sub-head</section>
      <section id="main-display">main display</section>
    </main>
  </article>
</body>
```

changed min-height to max-height and removed padding added some styles.

Comment: Please add proper details which solved the  issue so future reader don't have to go through whole code. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `box-sizing` property isn't inherited, so you can add:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

or at least add `box-sizing: border-box` to the sections that have padding on them. Without it, the browser ignores the padding when sizing them, so the additional padding causes them to overflow.

Comment: @Leothelion He has it on the body tag, not on the * selector, so the section elements don't inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

What's causing the issue is that the width of the sidebar is calculated wrong, because of the padding that's applied to the elements inside it.

When you add `box-sizing` for all elements, your problem will be solved.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Added */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

#code-html,
#code-css,
#code-js {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#code-html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

#code-css {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#code-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#main-run {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#main-display {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <section id="code-html">section 1</section>
      <section id="code-css">section 2</section>
      <section id="code-js">section 3</section>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <section id="main-run">sub-head</section>
      <section id="main-display">main display</section>
    </main>
  </article>
</body>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the CSS code below to the top. Because when you do not assign the `box-sizing: border-box;` property to an element, it will add padding values to the width. So the CSS below is a general CSS rule to apply to all elements.

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and please also update width `100vw` to `100%` from `artical` because it generate horizontal scoll bar at below.

```
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflow */
}
```

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflow */
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px; /* Limit the width */
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Add scrollbar if content exceeds 100vh */
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

#code-html,
#code-css,
#code-js {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#code-html {
  height: 30%; /* Set height to 30% */
  min-height: 100px; /* Set minimum height */
  background-color: red;
}

#code-css {
  height: 30%; /* Set height to 30% */
  min-height: 100px; /* Set minimum height */
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#code-js {
  height: 30%; /* Set height to 30% */
  min-height: 100px; /* Set minimum height */
  background-color: aqua;
}

#main-run {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#main-display {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Let it grow to fill remaining space */
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <section id="code-html">section 1</section>
      <section id="code-css">section 2</section>
      <section id="code-js">section 3</section>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <section id="main-run">sub-head</section>
      <section id="main-display">main display</section>
    </main>
  </article>
</body>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

#code-html,
#code-css,
#code-js {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#code-html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

#code-css {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#code-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 30%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#main-run {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#main-display {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <section id="code-html">section 1</section>
      <section id="code-css">section 2</section>
      <section id="code-js">section 3</section>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <section id="main-run">sub-head</section>
      <section id="main-display">main display</section>
    </main>
  </article>
</body>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```